# Laravel & vue.js - not rendering imported component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm starting to play around with vue.js on top of the laravel framework.

But im having trouble with rendering of a component which is imported.

My `app.js` (main entry point)

```js
// app.js
var Vue = require('vue');
var Router = require('vue-router');

Vue.use(Router);

var router = new Router();

var ContractsOverview = Vue.extend({
    template: '<p>contract page</p>'
});

var ContractDetail = Vue.extend({
    template: '<p>detail page</p>'
});

import DashboardView from './app/components/DashboardView.vue';

router.map({
    '/dashboard': {
        component: DashboardView
    },
    '/contracts': {
        component: ContractsOverview
    },
    '/contracts/:id': {
        component: ContractDetail
    }
});

var App = Vue.extend({
});

router.redirect({
    '*': '/dashboard'
});

router.start(App, '#reminder-app');
```

This is my Dashboard component 
(located at `resources/assets/js/app/components/DashboardView.vue`)

```html
<template>
    <section class="content-header">
    <h1>
    Dashboard
    <small>Control panel</small>
    </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
    </ol>
</section>
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <!-- .. some html -->
</section>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>
```

and in my master layout i have a normal blade template with the `<router-view></router-view>` tag at one point.

At the end i build my app.js with laravels elixir and the following gulpfile:

```js
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir.config.js.browserify.transformers.push({
    name: 'vueify',
    options: {}
});

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less(['bootstrap.less', 'app.less']);

    mix.scripts([
        'admin-lte/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js',
        'admin-lte/plugins/jQueryUI/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js',
        // some more scripts,
        'admin-lte/app.js',
        'admin-lte/pages/dashboard.js',
        'admin-lte/demo.js'

    ], 'public/js/ui.js');

    mix.browserify('app.js');
});
```

When i go to the page the routes `/contracts` and `contracts/:id` the templates are shown as expected.
But when i go the `/dashboard` route, i dont see anything (besides the layout).

Am I missing something? Did I forget to import or require something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i spent at least 4 hours finding my error, but it was just a simple typo somewhere.

But if you run `gulp` inside the virtual machine (homestead), you dont get the same output as if you run `gulp` locally. On my local machine it told what went wrong.

Also `gulp watch` doesn't work on the homestead machine.